# I am trying to read data, sort it, so I can determine peak values of a data set

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, printf, difference

I am trying to read data from a file that contains ECG data. I have the file being open and all the numbers being stored into an array. I have a while statement to keep it running while I have data in the file. I am trying to get the code to read that data into one array and then sort them into another array. Whenever I do this it doesn't give me any errors but the command prompt comes up with nothing in it and it doesn't terminate. Am I storing into the other array wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int X[128];
    int R[128];
    int S[128];
    int peak;
    int i = 0;

    FILE*fp_read= NULL;
    fp_read = fopen("ECG_data_128Hz_C.txt","r");

    while(i<128)
    {
        fscanf(fp_read, "%dC", &X[i]);
        //printf("%d\n",X[i]);

       if(X[i]>110)
        {
           scanf("%d",&R[i]);
           printf("R-Wave:%d\n",R[i]);
           break;
        }
        else if(X[i]<-50)
        {
            scanf("%d",&S[i]);
            printf("S-Wave: %d\n");
            break;
        }
        //peak = R[i] - S[i];
        //printf("Time between: %d\n",peak);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the exact source code you are compiling? There seem to be missing at least two curly braces in this version.

This code reads also from standard input, the terminal. With the code you shared, I don't see any attempt to sort. What exactly are you expecting as an output?

Comment: Never, *never* ignore the return value of fscanf().  %dC?

Comment: You have a broken printf statement

Comment: `scanf("%d",&R[i]);` - don't you want to read this data from the file (use `fscanf`)?

Comment: You don't need to sort data to find out the peak value. Just read everything in sequence and, whenever a new value is greater than a maximum-so-far, replace the maximum-so-far with the new one. Consider a special case of the very first item and you're done.

Comment: If you read `R[i]`, then you don't read `S[i]`, yet you increment `i` but the other array element has no (valid) data.

Comment: Suggestion: Turn on more warnings when compiling.

Comment: Why use `break`? That will exit the `while` loop.

Comment: The logic seems to be broken. `if(X[i]>110)` you read the next value into `R[i]`. and `else if(X[i]<-50)` you read the next value into `S[i]`. This will leave either `R[i]` or `S[i]` uninitialized. Please put a few lines from the file `ECG_data_128Hz_C.txt` into the question and also show what the expected result would be if the program used that data as input.

Comment: @HansPassant: I agree that you should never ignore what `fscanf()` returns.  However, the format string `"%dC"` provides no way to know whether the `C` (presumably for ºC) is matched or not.  It will return EOF, 0 or 1, regardless of whether the letter `C` matches or not.  You can't tell whether trailing literal characters are matched or not — you have to add `%n` after the literal and provide an extra variable to receive that count, which must be initialized before the call is made to the scanning function: `int read_C = 0; if (fscanf(fp_read, "%dC%n", &X[i], &read_C) == 1 && read_C != 0)`…

Comment: If your first thought is "I want to read into an array and then sort the data into another array", your second thought should be "I should use a data structure other than an array."